# Ionic 3 Angular 4 Cordova not able draw anything on canvas

Tags: angular, cordova, canvas, ionic3, angular6

I am developing one image editor application. In which, giving facility to user to draw anything on canvas. Currently using image as a background for canvas. Even after removing image from canvas, I am not able to draw anything on view. Below I have provided my code, any solution will be appreciable.

1. image-home.html

```html
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>image-home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding no-bounce>
    <canvas (touchstart)='handleMove($event)' (touchmove)='handleMove($event)' [ngStyle]="{'background': '#fff url('  + selectedImage + ') no-repeat 0 0'}" #canvas ></canvas>

</ion-content>



<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab [root]="chatRoot" tabTitle="Chat" tabIcon="chat"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="chatRoot" tabTitle="Edit" tabIcon="chat"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

2. image-home.scss

```scss
page-image-home {
    .tabbar {
        opacity: 1 !important;
    }

    .selectedImage{
        height: 80%;
    }

    canvas {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: center;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    #top-toolbar{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }

    #bottom-toolbar {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }

}
```

3. image-home.ts

```ts
    import { Component, ViewChild,  ElementRef, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

/**
 * Generated class for the ImageHomePage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-image-home',
  templateUrl: 'image-home.html',
})
export class ImageHomePage {
  @ViewChild('canvas') public canvas: ElementRef;
  @Input() public width = 400;
  @Input() public height = 400;

  private cx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;  

  selectedImage = "";
  lastX: number;
  lastY: number;
  currentColour: string = '#1abc9c';
  availableColours: any;

  brushSize: number = 10;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.selectedImage = this.navParams.get('id');
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    // this.selectedImage = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ImageHomePage');
    const canvasEl: HTMLCanvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
    this.cx = canvasEl.getContext('2d');

    // set the width and height
    canvasEl.width = this.width;
    canvasEl.height = this.height;

    // set some default properties about the line
    this.cx.beginPath();
    this.cx.moveTo(50, 10);
    this.cx.lineTo(10, 70);
    this.cx.lineTo(90, 70);
    this.cx.fill();
  }


  handleStart(ev){

        this.lastX = ev.touches[0].pageX;
        this.lastY = ev.touches[0].pageY;
    }

    handleMove(ev){

      const canvasEl: HTMLCanvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
      this.cx = canvasEl.getContext('2d');
        let currentX = ev.touches[0].pageX;
        let currentY = ev.touches[0].pageY;

        this.cx.beginPath();
        this.cx.lineJoin = "round";
        this.cx.moveTo(this.lastX, this.lastY);
        this.cx.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
        this.cx.closePath();
        this.cx.strokeStyle = this.currentColour;
        this.cx.lineWidth = this.brushSize;
        this.cx.stroke();      

        this.lastX = currentX;
        this.lastY = currentY;

    }


}
```

Comment: _I am not able to draw anything on view_. What do you mean? are you getting errors in console?

Comment: @SurajRao- I am not getting any kinda error. But as we can see normally we can draw on canvas using above methods. But in ionic 3, I am getting issue. Even I replaced everything with Canvas element, still same issue. Not getting draw anything on canvas

Comment: I think the issue is with the observable... Is the subscribe working?

Comment: I have updated my code. Now no more observable. On touch I m calling one method. Call is proper, I can inspect in chrome. But its not drawing anything. Can you please help out?

Comment: I tried this exact code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-asufj8?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts). Its working fine

Comment: But.. why do you have tabs in the bottom? are you loading another page?

Comment: It's working on browser but not on device. I am checking on android device. Not able to see anything.

Comment: have you tried remote debugging and checked console?

Comment: Yes.. I did remote debugging also. It's just showing me info that violation of touch event. Nothing than that. Even I removed everything like tab and canvas background image. Still I am not able to see triangle as you can see on web browser.

Comment: which device? android version?..As far as code goes.. Nothing seems to be wrong.

Comment: Currently I am using android emulator. API 2, Android 7.1.1

Comment: Just for new update.. It working in ios simulator. But now issue is that  drawing is not getting start from where I touch. It starting from below it.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
<canvas (touchstart)='handleMove($event)' ...
```

to

```
<canvas (touchstart)='handleStart($event)' ...
```

and if it still doesnt work .take a look at this link:

https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-drawing-application-in-ionic/